# How do I prove that the product of two closed sets is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Given $A \in \mathbb{R^q}$ and  $B \in \mathbb{R^p}$ two closed sets, then
$A \times B$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R^m} = \mathbb{R^q} \times \mathbb{R^p}$

How do I prove the previous result by using sequences?

Comment: Look at the answer of @MartinSleziak in the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a convergent sequence $(a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2), \ldots$ in $A \times B$, then show the point of convergence is in $A \times B$ by looking at each component separately.